Navigation with floating image


const navBar = document.getElementById('nav-bar');


function moveSkateboard() {
    const skateboard = document.querySelector('div');
    let position = 0;
    let direction = 1;
    let speed = 1;

    function move() {
        position += direction * speed;
        skateboard.style.left = position + 'px';
        if (position >= window.innerWidth - skateboard.offsetWidth) {
        direction = -1;
        } else if (position <= 0) {
        direction = 1;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(move);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

moveSkateboard();
header {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 155, 68, 1);
}

img {
    width: 10%;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    height: 6.125em;
}


nav a {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color:#009344;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}

nav div {
    background: no-repeat center/70% url("../images/skateboard-navBar.png") ;
    width: 5.9375em;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
<header>
        <img src="./images/btrLogoBlack.png" alt="BTR Logo">
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="events.html">Events</a>
            <a href="donate.html">Donate</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <div></div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    
    <p>In the nav bar there is a skateboard moving left to right and back, but it is the length of the window. The javaScript has window.innerWidth because I could not figure out how to only make it the width of the nav. But I wanted to know if my thought process would work. Now unfortunately I am stuck.</p>



I am relatively new to coding. I am trying to get a skateboard to run back and forth my nav bar. The nav bar differs from the window's width, so I know I cannot check the window.InnerWidth. If I made the nav bar the width of a window, then sure. I am having trouble figuring out how to have it run the width of the nav bar and back. First - Do I need to style the element in JavaScript, or can it stay in CSS? Second, what do I use to measure the width of an element?
Ultimately, I want to use just 40% of the animation width.
Thank you for any help.

Hi Karen, welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we have our own version of Codepens, we call them Stack Snippets. So if you can please edit your post to include one of these, it would be perfect. We don’t like relying on external links, because they could break in future.

A note on your first question, IMHO, though one can style in JS, CSS is for styling. You can always use JS to add/remove/toggle a class styled in CSS.

I figured it out by adding a width to my function. It flows wonderfully now that I replaced windows.innerWidth with just width.  Thank you, Brett, for teaching me about Stack Snippets. I will know for the future.

You should try this it will work fine for you as you want to run skateboard according to nav width. Just make some changes to your Javascript code.


const navBar = document.getElementById('nav-bar');


function moveSkateboard() {
  const skateboard = document.querySelector('div');
  let position = 0;
  let direction = 1;
  let speed = 1;
  **const navWidht = document.getElementById("nav-bar")**

  function move() {
    position += direction * speed;
    skateboard.style.left = position + 'px';
    if (position >= **navWidht.offsetWidth** - skateboard.offsetWidth) {
      direction = -1;
    } else if (position <= 0) {
      direction = 1;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

moveSkateboard();



